# Cannot destructure property 'history' of 'undefined' as it is undefined. --React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, history

I used 'history' object in a Component of Router which is AddMovie component. But after three lines, I used again it and it gives this error:
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'history' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.

```js
 77 |    <Route path="/add" render = { ({history}) => (
 78 |   <AddMovie onAddMovieprop={(newMovie) => { this.addMovie(newMovie); history.push("/"); }} />
  79 | )}>
  80 | </Route>
> 81 | <Route path="/edit/:id" render = { ( props, {history} ) => (
     | ^  82 |   <EditMovie {...props} onEditMovieProp = {(id, updatedMovie) => { this.editMovie(id, updatedMovie); this.props.history.push("/"); }}/>
  83 |     )}>
  84 | </Route>
```

How can I fix it? Line 78 and Line 82 are nearly same how can it be possible?

Here is part of render of my App.js code :

```js
render(){
    let filteredMovies = this.state.movies.filter(
      movie => { return (movie.name.indexOf(this.state.searchQuery.toLowerCase()) !== -1) }
    ).sort((a,b) => {
      return a.name > b.name ? 1 : b.name> a.name ? -1 : 0; 
    })
    return (
     <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact render = {() => (
              <div className="container" >
                <Searcher searchMovieProp = {this.searchMovie} addHistoryProp = {this.addHistory} />
                <MovieList movies= {filteredMovies} removeMovieProp = {this.removeMovie} />
              </div>
            )}>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/add" render = { ({history}) => (
              <AddMovie onAddMovieprop={(newMovie) => { this.addMovie(newMovie); history.push("/"); }} />
            )}>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/edit/:id" render = { ( props, {history} ) => (
              <EditMovie {...props} onEditMovieProp = {(id, updatedMovie) => { this.editMovie(id, updatedMovie); history.push("/"); }}/>
                )}>
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
     </Router>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need to do:

```
<Route
  path="/edit/:id"
  render={({history, ...props}) => (
    <EditMovie
      {...props}
      onEditMovieProp={(id, updatedMovie) => {
        this.editMovie(id, updatedMovie);
        history.push("/");
      }}
    />
  )}
></Route>;
```

Answer (score 0):

It gives you the error because `this.props` is undefined on that line
Change

```
this.props.history.push("/");
```

to

```
history.push("/")
```

Comment: Seems like they already made that change in the source code included in the question. But not in the code in the error traceback. In any case, the specific error was actually thrown in the line before this.

Comment: Line 82: OP has `this.props.history.push` in the source code included in the question. This is why OP gets the error.